# Sequelize: different handling of transactions

Tags: sql, node.js, t-sql, sequelize.js

Lets say we have implemented a couple of (dummy) services using Sequelize models to access our DB:

```
export class AService {
    // ... some other stuff
    async updateSomeA(aId: number, value: string) {

        let instanceA = await ModelA.findById(aId);

        // need this update to use the transaction!
        await instanceA.update({
            some_field: value
        });
    }

}

export class BService {
    // ... some other stuff
    async updateB(bId: number, value: string) {

        let instanceB = await ModelB.findById(bId);

        // and this one as well!
        await instanceB.update({
            some_field_in_b: value
        });
    }
}
```

Now we want to call `updateSomeA` and `updateB` from somewhere else in our code, say from `CService`, but we want those calls wrapped within a transaction.

```
class CService {

    // ...stuff

    async f() {

        // == begin transaction
        await AService.updateSomeA(1, 'blah!');
        await BService.updateB(3, 'meh');
        // == end transaction
    }
}
```

From what I gather going through [the docs](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/transactions/), in order to protect the code with a transaction, I either need to wrap it in a callback or use a promise. Is that right?

If that's the case, then I'd be forced to modify my services and probably have some 'transaction capable' versions of my methods, correct?

Do you guys know if there are plans of supporting something like

```
Transaction.begin("myAwesomeTransaction");

// ... every SQL generated in here is 'safe'

Transaction.end();
```

### EDIT: The *"transaction as an argument"* solution

Sure, we can always take the transaction as an optional last argument in all of our service functions, or at least the ones with side effects (i.e. `deleteA`, `updateB`, etc.). Something like:

```
// ... changed AService.updateSomeA
async updateSomeA(aId: number, value: string, t?: Sequelize.Transaction) {

    let instanceA = await ModelA.findById(aId);
    await instanceA.update({
        some_field: value
    }, {
        transaction: t  // we use the transaction if we get one
    });
}
```

But what happens with our `CService.f()`? Should this function create the transaction and pass it down, or expect a transaction as an optional argument? Well, the answer is both, isn't it? If we are calling `f()` from some other service as part of a larger transaction, we expect it to receive that `Transaction` instance and use it. On the other hand, if we are calling `f()` from *the outside* (e.g. a controller), we don't want to be creating transactions over there... right?!

So, we end up with something like:

```
// ... changed CService.f
async f(t?: Sequelize.Transaction) {

    if(!t) return sequelize.transaction(_f); // using the autoCallback overload
    else return _f(t);

    async function _f(trans: Sequelize.Transaction) {

        // ... actual code for f() goes here
    }
}
```

Perfect? Nah... Looking forward to your input!

Comment: Would creating a transaction and adding it to the services work? So call `update` with the transaction if the transaction argument exists.

Comment: @user3254198 Yeah, adding the extra optional argument to every function was exactly what I was trying to avoid but...

Comment: The transactions in `sequelize` gets resolved with `promises`. So indeed, passing down the transaction would be the way. You do not want to be creating this transaction in your controller but when you actually are going to need it. Not before and certainly not after. But the way you want it to work (e.g. global transaction defined and this also running the the other files) will not work with `sequelize`